# Request API with Bearer token

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use the Malwarebytes API to get data. However, I am not getting the results for request. I get the "Unauthorized" message. My understanding of the documentation is to get the "access token" using my client ID and client secret. I was able to get the access token. However, I am not sure how to run the access token I received to the headers so I can get data. help is appreciated.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
import requests
import json



CLIENT_ID = "Client id "
CLIENT_SECRET = "client secret"

grant_type = 'client_credentials'
body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type}

url='https://api.malwarebytes.com/oneview/oauth2/token'
response = requests.post(url, data=body_params, auth = (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)) 



#Gets only access token
response_token = response.json()
response_token2 = json.dumps(response_token, indent=2)
token_response = response_token.get("access_token",[0])




##BEARER AUTHORIZATION
headers = {
    'Authorization':'Bearer token_response',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

companies = requests.get('https://api.malwarebytes.com/oneview/v1/sites', headers=headers)
print(companies.text)
print(companies.status_code)
```

Issue with getting data after getting access token